# Improve performance of tagging algorithm using array of tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

Here is my class `Sample`.

A `Sample` instance can:

- have a number of tags such as `Tag1`, `Tag2`, etc.
- be queried with method `isTagged` to find out whether it has been tagged or not tagged (ie. `!Tag1`)

```js
    function Sample(){
        // [..]
        this.tags = [];
        // [..]
    }

    Sample.prototype.tag = function(tags){
        // [..]
        this.tags[tags] = true;
        // [..]
    };

    // if an array is passed, isTagged will return true at the first match ie. not all need to match, just one
    Sample.prototype.isTagged = function(tag){

        if(tag){
            if(Array.isArray(tag)){

                let tLength = tag.length;

                while(tLength--){
                    if(isTaggedSingleNoChecks(this, tag[tLength])){
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
            else{
                return isTaggedSingleNoChecks(this, tag);
            }
        }

        return false;
    };

    function isTaggedSingleNoChecks(sample, tag){
        const isNegated = tag.charAt(0) == "!";
                
        if(isNegated){
            tag = tag.replace(/^[!]/, "");

            return sample.tags[tag]!==true;    
        }
        else{
            return sample.tags[tag]===true; 
        }
    }
    
    // showing usage
    var sample = new Sample();
    sample.tag('Tag1'); 
    sample.tag('Tag2');
    
    console.log(sample.isTagged('Tag1'));
    console.log(sample.isTagged('Tag3'));
    console.log(sample.isTagged('!Tag2'));
```

This all works great however my application recursively queries `isTagged` millions of times on thousands of instances of `Sample`, and my profiling is showing this to be a performance bottleneck.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance?

Comment: You could build an index of tags. The downside is, of course, increased housekeeping.

Comment: Why your app is calling it so much times? Maybe add some cache for it?

Comment: @SamiHult - how would you do that?

Comment: @Justinas - how would you add a cache which would make this quicker?

Comment: `if (typeof this.cache[tag] !== 'undefined'){return this.cache[tag]} else {this.cache[tag] = this.checkIsTagged()} return this.cache[tag];`

Comment: @Justinas - how can that be any quicker? You are just adding extra instructions to the execution...

Comment: I will take back the comment on indexing for a while. After all, you only have thousands of `Sample`s so even if that would prove to be an upgrade, it would probably not be worthwhile. You should probably look for improvements elsewhere in your code, since thousands of entries ignite millions of tests. Can you share the code where your current approach becomes a problem?

Comment: @SamiHult - I think what you are saying makes sense... Unfortunately I cannot easily share the rest of the application...

Answer (score 1):

Before you start optimizing this, how about simplifying the code first and getting rid of the most obvious oddities (objects instead of Sets, useless regexes etc)

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.tags = new Set();
    }

    tag(...tags) {
        for (let t of tags)
            this.tags.add(t);
    }

    isTagged(...tags) {
        return tags.some(t =>
            (t[0] === '!')
                ? !this.tags.has(t.slice(1))
                : this.tags.has(t)
        )
    }
}
```

If this is still too slow, then you have to resort to a global object-tag inverted index, for example:

```
class SetMap extends Map {
    get(key) {
        if (!this.has(key))
            this.set(key, new Set)
        return super.get(key)
    }
}

let tagIndex = new SetMap()


class Sample {
    tag(...tags) {
        for (let t of tags) {
            tagIndex.get(t).add(this)
        }
    }

    isTagged(...tags) {
        return tags.some(t => tagIndex.get(t).has(this))
    }
}
```

Of course, some more work will be involved for untagging (tag removal) and, especially, proper serialization.

The index won't immediately speed up `isTagged` per se, but will greatly optimize queries "find objects that are tagged by X and/or Y".

Comment: Thanks for the reply... The code is written this way because it is then translated using browserify to run on the browser and I found that letting browserify/babel doing the transpiling made everything slower on IE11... Also I use objects rather than `Set` because in the real app (i simplified the code for the post) i set the value for the tag to a enum parameter (ie. single, start, end, middle)

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia: you could consider `Map` then... but the regex should go in any case (unless your search syntax is more complex than you posted)

Comment: removing regex did not make any noticeable difference in terms of performance... (profiling in chrome dev tools - from node.js, didn't try in IE)

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you think the index idea will perform faster? it has the same object access code (accessing the set), the set is much larger and the index key requires text concatenation... surely this would make it slower... no?

Comment: `Map` support for IE is rubbish... I just moved away from it as I just could not get it to work once i transpiled it and ran on IE